# Dual boot home premium with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows, windows-7

I am using a usb to dual boot windows home premium with ubuntu 14.04. But my problem is that whenever i Choose the option Install Ubuntu with windows side by side and click on install my laptop starts afresh the ubuntu installation from the first step. If i remove the usb just after clicking install then windows boots again. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to manually select (considering you create them first) separate partitions for ubuntu.

My current setup:

- C (win8.1)
- D (NTFS shared with both windows and ubuntu)
- an extended partition containing an ext4 (mount point /) and a swap

check out this [link](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html), a very descriptive step by step